# Sorting (order_by) in list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am building a Blog App and I am trying to `sort` or `order_by` in list which contains multiple queries.

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Comments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blog_of = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
def mypage(request):
    query_1 = list(BlogPost.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-date'))

    query_2 = list(Comment.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('date_added'))


    results = sorted(chain(query_1, query_2),key=attrgetter('date') , reverse=True)

    context = {'results':results}
    return render(reques, 'mypage.html', context)
```

But is showing

> 'Comment' object has no attribute 'date'

And I think this is because date field name is different in both model and i am sorting with only one, But i have no idea how can I sort with different field name.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Sorry, I got confused about that. Is there no way you can change the name of the `date_added` attribute to `date`?

Comment: Yes i can , but let me try it also

Comment: @kinshukdua, Thanks for your Help and precious suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just add it as a property:

```
class Comments(models.Model):  # do NOT give a model a plural name!
    # ....
    @property
    def date(self):
        return self.date_added
        # or if it is a datetimefield
        # return self.date_added.date()
```

ALso you can just write a more customized sorting key (e.g. in case the involved models are from third-party apps).

```
def order(obj):
    try:
        return obj.date
    except AttributeError:
        return obj.date_added

# ...
results = sorted(chain(query_1, query_2), key=order, reverse=True)
```

Comment: No it doesn't solve (First Answer) it shows the same error, But turning every `DateTimeField` field name into `date` did the trick. Does using same name for every date field make `bad impact` ?

Comment: With second edit, You mean `function` inside `function` ?

Comment: Doesn't matter where you define that function (not as a method of a class though). ALso, you can call all date fields "date", but I would always go with more telling names, e.g. "date_added", "date_changed", etc. Once you have two date fields on the same model, you have to come up with a different name anyway.